# Cordova build failed with an exception: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, gradle, sapui5

I am getting below error on CMD when i run the command Cordova compile android or cordova build.

```
D:\Cordova\NewCordova\hogya>cordova compile android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\29556\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
................................................................................
.....
Unzipping C:\Users\29556\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jb
ap0tjew\gradle-4.1-all.zip to C:\Users\29556\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-al
l\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could
not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :CordovaLib
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools
/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/buil
d/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
               > Connect to 10.6.13.208:8080 [/10.6.13.208] failed: Connection t
imed out: connect
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/bu
ild/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/g
radle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
               > Connect to 10.6.13.208:8080 [/10.6.13.208] failed: Connection t
imed out: connect
   > Could not resolve com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5.
     Required by:
         project :CordovaLib
      > Could not resolve com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/dcende
nts/android-maven-gradle-plugin/1.5/android-maven-gradle-plugin-1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/dcendents/an
droid-maven-gradle-plugin/1.5/android-maven-gradle-plugin-1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 10.6.13.208:8080 [/10.6.13.208] failed: Connection t
imed out: connect
      > Could not resolve com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/github/dcendents
/android-maven-gradle-plugin/1.5/android-maven-gradle-plugin-1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/github/dcendents/andro
id-maven-gradle-plugin/1.5/android-maven-gradle-plugin-1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 10.6.13.208:8080 [/10.6.13.208] failed: Connection t
imed out: connect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 16s
(node:5548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with ex
it code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :CordovaLib
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools
/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/buil
d/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
               > Connect to 10.6.13.208:8080 [/10.6.13.208] failed: Connection t
imed out: connect
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/bu
ild/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/g
radle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
               > Connect to 10.6.13.208:8080 [/10.6.13.208] failed: Connection t
imed out: connect
   > Could not resolve com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5.
     Required by:
         project :CordovaLib
      > Could not resolve com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/dcende
nts/android-maven-gradle-plugin/1.5/android-maven-gradle-plugin-1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/dcendents/an
droid-maven-gradle-plugin/1.5/android-maven-gradle-plugin-1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 10.6.13.208:8080 [/10.6.13.208] failed: Connection t
imed out: connect
      > Could not resolve com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/github/dcendents
/android-maven-gradle-plugin/1.5/android-maven-gradle-plugin-1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/github/dcendents/andro
id-maven-gradle-plugin/1.5/android-maven-gradle-plugin-1.5.pom'.
               > Connect to 10.6.13.208:8080 [/10.6.13.208] failed: Connection t
imed out: connect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 16s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (D:\Cordova\NewCordova\hogya\platforms\android\cord
ova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:5548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection
 id: 1)
(node:5548) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`
```

I have already tried uninstalling cordova and ANdroid studio and again installing them. Also i have already tried by adding google() in build.gradle file in my cordova project.
Please help me resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Warm Regards,
Kunj Bihari Shukla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really must add `google()` as a repository. By your log, it seems that gradle is searching for the gradle plugin only at `jcenter` and `maven` repositories and they don't have that plugin (at least on that version).

One option is to add google() to `init.gradle`

1. Locate `.gradle` folder under your "Documents" directory.. It is located usually at: `C:\Users\<YOUR_USER_NAME>\.gradle`
2. Create a file `init.gradle` inside that folder: `C:\Users\<YOUR_USER_NAME>\.gradle\init.gradle`
3. Paste following code on that file:

   ```
   allprojects {
       buildscript.repositories {
           google()
           jcenter({ url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" })
           maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
       }

       repositories {
           google()
           jcenter({ url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" })
           maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
       }
   }
   ```

This is one option to solve that... This way, you add `google()`, `jcenter()` and `maven()` repositories to all of your projects.

Comment: Thanks @W0rmH0le now my build is happening successfully